# Get access token from Microsoft Graph for Azure

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have this code below to try to get an access token from Microsoft Graph. Using the query in Postman works great. But whenever I tried in node I am having this error: ***The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'.***

What am I missing here please? Im really stuck. (the value for grant_type is 'password')

```js
// GET TOKEN
alterState(state => {
  const { host, userName, password, scope, client_secret, client_id, tenant_id, grant_type } = state.configuration;

  const data = {
    grant_type: grant_type,
    client_id: client_id,
    client_secret: client_secret,
    scope: scope,
    userName: userName,
    password: password,
  };

  return post(
    `${host}${tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token`,
    {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
      body: data
      
    },
    state => {
      console.log(state);
    }
  )(state);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Actually data for the post should not be sent as **body** but as **form**.

So by doing this below you have the access token:

```js
return post(
    url,
    {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
      form: data
      
    })
```